# Output replacement summary in ant replaceregexp task

Tags: regex, ant, replace, summary

Is there a `summary="true"` equivalent in ant `replaceregexp` tasks like there is in the simple ant `replace` task?

Here's my use case.  I am replacing an ant replace task with a replaceregexp task, like so:

```
<replace dir="${dir}" summary="true" value="" token="Some Text">
    <include name="**/*.jsp" />
</replace>
```

Becomes this:

```
<replaceregexp byline="true">
    <regexp pattern="Some\s*Text"/>
    <substitution expression=""/>
 <fileset dir="${dir}" includes="**/*.jsp"/>
</replaceregexp>
```

However, I cannot find a way to have my ant build output the number of replacements which have been made.  There is no `summary` attribute for `replaceregexp`, and the documentation does not offer any ready suggestions.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From reading the source of ReplaceRegexp task there ain't such a feature.
ant184 => src/main/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/optional/ReplaceRegExp.java, line 351 :

```
protected void doReplace(File f, int options) throws IOException {
        File temp = FILE_UTILS.createTempFile("replace", ".txt", null, true, true);

        Reader r = null;
        Writer w = null;
        BufferedWriter bw = null;

        try {
            if (encoding == null) {
                r = new FileReader(f);
                w = new FileWriter(temp);
            } else {
                r = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(f), encoding);
                w = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(temp),
                                           encoding);
            }

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(r);
            bw = new BufferedWriter(w);

            boolean changes = false;

            log("Replacing pattern '" + regex.getPattern(getProject())
                + "' with '" + subs.getExpression(getProject())
                + "' in '" + f.getPath() + "'" + (byline ? " by line" : "")
                + (flags.length() > 0 ? " with flags: '" + flags + "'" : "")
                + ".", Project.MSG_VERBOSE);
```

means use loglevel verbose to log the replacements:
`ant -verbose -f yourfile.xml`
or
`ant -v -f yourfile.xml`

Get the [ant source distribution file](http://ant.apache.org/srcdownload.cgi) and simply extend the tasks doReplace() method to get your desired output, for example, a counter for the replacements, controlled by a new task attribute 'summary' false|true
You may fill an [enhancement report](http://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=Ant&bug_severity=enhancement) and submit a patch to make it available for other users in the next ant release, more details [here](http://ant.apache.org/bugs.html).